# I want to call Node.js Function Fom RestFul Webserivce in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I want call node.js function from rest web service  . When all process is done then i want to call node.js function But i cant call node.js function. Can anyone suggest me how is it possible .
                          Please Reply As possible as.﻿

Comment: Do you mean you want to call node.js function from PHP?? Do some research on it.

Comment: I have done using DNode Libary. Its work for me. Or we can use curl .

Comment: DNode is a good option.